# Need Help Identifying Encryption and Decoding JSON Data

Tags: json

I have encountered a JSON file with what appears to be encoded data, and I suspect it might be encrypted. I’m seeking assistance in identifying the encryption method used and decoding the data.

URL: http://a500.variety-buy.store/api/channel/1422

Here is a snippet of the encoded JSON data:

```
GAMcOx5KbAN9PGIrFy0TVQsUCBEaGkdHWhNZAxAuHlt0ZQkbbzcTclgWUxtaV1gWUVpbbUxNESwPd2EPF3Jxd0F4Tk8GDmUcX1ZWUE4fDhINYlVfc39lcC4mBjIAAn5UDmJCf1ZHYlsMZyl8DxZ/Dx90dn1AcUBGExobRkRUbUFPQQYDQmlGCTtKQzUfJBElGAMTDBsRGhpAUFBUEUQKeFAJbBUELyUkEiUEBBMMYm5LZU8=
```

Comment: This is not JSON. It's BASE64 encoded binary.

Comment: yes you right i tried to decode it to base64 but i didn't got results! but the final decoded data is json i'm sure of that

Comment: _"the final decoded data is json"_ How do you know that if you can't decode it? I find this domain on block lists, the headers are questionable, and there's no base site. This smells funny to me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not buying it. Akamai lists this domain as high risk known malware. Voting to close.

Comment: I told you that I am sure that the content, if decrypted, will be json because the origin of this API is a an app for watching channels, and I made an intercept to find out http requests and i found this api url encrypted

Comment: you can see the intercepted requests screenshot:
https://ibb.co/vxCFWz6